# Count the frequency of occurance for words from one array in another array in PHP

Tags: php

Suppose that I have the two following arrays:

```
$array1 = ['Apple','Juice']
$array2 = ['Apple Juice', 'Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Juice', 'Pineapple']
```

I want an efficient way using PHP built-in functions to count the number of times that the words in $array1 appear in each element of $array2 and output something like this

```
$output = array(
'Apple Juice' => 2,
'Apple' => 1
'Red Apple' => 1,
'Juice' => 1,
'Pineapple' => 0
);
```

I know I can use for loops, but a cleverer way that uses PHP built-in functions that consumes less memory and works faster is much appreciated. I know that Python has built-in functions for vector calculations and manipulations, but I'm not aware of such tools in PHP. Hence, the question.

Edit: In case of 'Apple Juice Apple', let's count this case as 3 for simplicity.

Comment: For 5 elements in array you won't gain anything. Just write the working code and optimize it when and __if__ time comes.

Comment: At least show us what solution you currently have. Otherwise, this is IMHO nothing but a thinly veiled “someone write it for me”.

Comment: @CBRoe I can write it using for loops obviously. I can post the code if you want to see my attempt, but I thought it would get my post unnecessarily long and it will nearly nothing to the value of my question.

Comment: You’re gonna have to loop over both arrays one way or another. All the array functions provided, will have to do that internally as well. If you want to know what variant(s) perform better, then you need to create up a proper test setup, to run this logic a couple thousand times or more.

Comment: Can the second array also contain `'Apple Juice Apple'`, and if so, would the expected result then be 2 or 3?

Comment: @CBroe Well, I know Python has tools for vector calculations. I'm not aware of such functions in PHP, but it can simply be because of my ignorance. Good question. Well, I think if I count that as two, I will need to store more information in memory. So, let's count it as 3. I'll add that to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be my attempt, but again, you will have to actually run some performance tests on stuff like this, if you want to know what really performs best.

```
$array1 = ['Apple','Juice'];
$array2 = ['Apple Juice', 'Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Juice', 'Pineapple', 'Apple Juice Apple'];

// need the values of array1 as *keys* of an array, for array_intersect_keys to work
// I am providing it in static form here, but you can create it dynamically later
$array1_keys = ['Apple' => 1, 'Juice' => 1];
$result = [];

// use array_walk to avoid a “manual” loop
array_walk($array2, function($val, $key) use (&$result, $array1_keys) {
  // explode the words at space, to get an array
  $words = explode(' ', $val);
  // count how many times each word occurred
  $wordcounts = array_count_values($words);
  // intersect that with the keys of array1, to filter out the count of words
  // we are not interested in,
  // array_sum to sum up the values of the rest
  $result[$val] = array_sum(array_intersect_key($wordcounts, $array1_keys));
} );

var_dump($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/UBd8o, result:

```
array(6) {
  ["Apple Juice"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Apple"]=>
  int(1)
  ["Red Apple"]=>
  int(1)
  ["Juice"]=>
  int(1)
  ["Pineapple"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Apple Juice Apple"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution, I need to learn some of these tricks! Is `array_walk` generally better than a foreach loop?

Comment: I used it here as an example of how manual looping can be substituted by array functions, but … https://www.ktorides.com/2015/02/php-array_walk-vs-foreach/ says, _“One would expect the built-in function to be faster since its written in C and hopefully has been highly optimized but it turns out, that’s not the case. After a bit of online research and some tests, foreach is the clear winner.”_

Comment: And on the other hand, https://medium.com/@steveclifton_12558/array-walk-performance-test-b8cfb11511a8 says, _“At this stage, I am pretty confident there is no real world benefit to using array_walk() over using foreach(). It doesn't provide an increase in performance, nor does it read better than a foreach loop would, so in this case, I don’t think that ill be needing to use this array function often in my day-to-day code.”_

Comment: I think for the loop over array1, the difference will be minimal here, whether you walk or foreach it. More important is probably the calculation for each item _inside_ the loop, there you could choose different approaches again - like, don’t split `'Apple Juice'` into individual words, but use `strpos` in that string value directly to figure out whether that contains `Apple`, or other stuff like that. (But especially for the `Apple Juice Apple` value and counting that as 3, `strpos` would be rather bad, because you’d need to loop with _that_ again then, starting of at the last position …)

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was expecting. Thanks. Although I am surprised that array_walk doesn't perform better than a foreach loop. I remember once I had to do image processing in Python and MATLAB (I was doing a homography transformation to an image), and when I used for loops, it took about 120 to 140 seconds but when I used vector tools available in those languages, it was reduced to like 6 to 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = ['Apple','Juice'];
$array2 = ['Apple Juice', 'Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Juice', 'Pineapple']; 

//create output array
$output = [];

foreach($array2 as $v) {
    
    //create key in `$output` equal to `$v`, with a value of 0
    $output[$v] = 0;

    //split value of `$v` into an array of words
    $values = explode(" ", $v);

    //loop through split values of `$v`
    foreach($values as $value) {

        //check if value from split values is in `$array1`
        if(in_array($value, $array1)) {

            //increment `$output` array for key equal to `$v`
            $output[$v] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Apple Juice] => 2
    [Apple] => 1
    [Red Apple] => 1
    [Juice] => 1
    [Pineapple] => 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is correct, but I am also looking for a more efficient way instead of using just two for loops. But it is correct.

Comment: @stressedout Well you are probably going to need to do some kind of loop no matter what, whether it's verbose in your code or not. Plus, any efficiency difference is going to be very minimal, and probably not worth the time for micro-optimization.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I know some languages like Python are capable of vector assignments and manipulations. I mean I have done such a thing in Python and MATLAB when doing image processing where I had two deal with large 2-dimmensional arrays (photos). I wonder if PHP has such capabilities too.

Comment: @stressedout I hope you get an answer which satisfies your question, but I'll leave this answer here for future visitors as well.

Comment: Please do so. Your answer is fine and I upvoted it too. If I don't get a better answer, I will be glad to accept this one.